# Mock GraphServiceClient Batch Call

Tags: .net, mocking, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to create a unit test for the following code:

```
var batchRequestContentCollection = new BatchRequestContentCollection(client);

var request = client.Users.Me.Messages[mailId].Content.ToGetRequestInformation();
await batchRequestContentCollection.AddBatchRequestStepAsync(request);

var response = await client.Batch.PostAsync(batchRequestContentCollection, cancellationToken);
```

I can mock everything up until `client.Batch`, like this:

Create an `IRequestAdapter` that I call `mockRequestAdapter` with

```
public static Mock<IRequestAdapter> Create(MockBehavior mockBehavior = MockBehavior.Strict)
{
    var mockSerializationWriterFactory = new Mock<ISerializationWriterFactory>();
    mockSerializationWriterFactory.Setup(factory => factory.GetSerializationWriter(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(new JsonSerializationWriter());

    var mockRequestAdapter = new Mock<IRequestAdapter>(mockBehavior);
    mockRequestAdapter.SetupGet(adapter => adapter.BaseUrl).Returns("https://localhost/");
    mockRequestAdapter.SetupSet(adapter => adapter.BaseUrl = It.IsAny<string>());
    mockRequestAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.EnableBackingStore(It.IsAny<IBackingStoreFactory>()));
    mockRequestAdapter.SetupGet(adapter => adapter.SerializationWriterFactory).Returns(mockSerializationWriterFactory.Object);

    return mockRequestAdapter;
}
```

then in `mockRequestAdapter` I setup the batch requests like this:

```
mockRequestAdapter.Setup(adapter => adapter.ConvertToNativeRequestAsync<HttpRequestMessage>(
    It.IsAny<RequestInformation>(),
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync((RequestInformation requestInformation, CancellationToken token) =>
    {
        var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
        var mailId = (string)requestInformation.PathParameters["message%2Did"];
        message.Content = new StringContent(mailId);
        return message;
    });
```

The `client.Batch` then calls `SendNoContentAsync` but then internal methods of `Graph` are called going from `BatchRequestBuilder` in `GraphServiceClient` to class `CustomBatchRequestBuilder` to class `BatchRequestBuilder` where there is the method

```
public async Task<BatchResponseContentCollection> PostAsync(BatchRequestContentCollection batchRequestContentCollection, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>> errorMappings = null)
```

that calls `var response = await PostAsync(request, cancellationToken, errorMappings);` which I cannot mock (or the parts after it).

I have spent multiple days tryinag anything from mocks to reflection trying to figure this out and I am wondering if there is an easier way to mock batch requests. Is there a trick to it?